# RequireJS and a multilanguage website

Tags: javascript, internationalization, requirejs

(warning: I am a newbie with require.js)

I am using the RequireJS Optimizer to combine all require.js JS files into one file and I don't know why the output JS file contains *only* the root bundle. 
My lang/nls/strings.js file is http://pastie.org/private/7o6fa7sfrxvppu4lcunz0a

And after running 'node r.js' there is no 'lang/nls/de/strings' declaration http://pastie.org/private/dyktxwv4wgdywbj8mltw , although I have a require/lang/nls/de/strings.js file

The build example of r.js https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js states that 'Only one locale can be inlined for a build' but I hope there is a way to include in the optimized file all the language strings that my app need. So how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As you read only one local can be inlined, which totally makes sense as you dont wanna load all locals, cause in most cases the user needs only one. RequireJS will automatically detect whats the browser local and load the missing locals if they exist. If you need all locals, dont use requireJS and inline them as plain JSON.